# how can i make media query work with min-with?

Tags: css, url, import, media

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* import the basis style page */
@import url("body.css");
/* why is this not working? */
/* import alternative style 500px */
@media (min-width: 500px){
  @import url("screen_layout_small.css");
}
```

The screen_layout_small.css file contains :

```
@charset "UTF-8";

body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

The url "screen_layout_small.css" works when it is not in a @media (works when it is not in a responsive command ?)

I tryed to load it when width >= 500px but it doesn't work.

By the way it does not mather if I use min-with or max-with, the file does not load in the @media.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a wrong syntax. It should be:

```
@import url|string list-of-mediaqueries;
```

So in your case it should be:

```
@import "screen_layout_small.css" screen and (min-width: 500px);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake is in the syntax. Try the code that I mentioned below

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* inport the basis style page */
@import url("body.css");
/* why is this not working???? */
/* import alternative style 500px*/
@media screen and (min-width: 500px){
@import url("screen_layout_small.css");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* inport the basis style page */
@import url("body.css");
/* import alternative style 500px*/
@import "screen_layout_small.css" screen and (max-width: 500px);
```

this is the working code thanks to maria romano